# Flickering Tab Control with MouseMove Determining What To Draw

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, flicker

I have been researching this all day, (Go ahead and laugh lol) and I don't see any solutions to the age old Forms problem of flickering controls. My control is a TabControl and I am using DrawMode OwnerDrawFixed. I am hooking the following events. In short I am creating a TabControl with closable "X" buttons that are 12x12 png resources. The close buttons are all gray but if I mouse over one it should use a different image (a red X).

1. MouseDown: Loops all TabPages and checks if I have clicked on a rectangle where I am drawing my close button image.
2. MouseLeave: I need to Invalidate when I leave the TabControl to ensure everything is drawn correctly
3. MouseMove: Loops all TabPages and checks if I have moused over a rectangle where I am drawing my close button image. If I am mousing over then I save the tab page index so my paint can change the image used for the close button.
4. DrawItem: Here I simply draw the image

Things I have tested but no luck...

1. Making my own TabControl class which inherits TabControl and in the constructor I SetStyles for OptimizedDoubleBuffering To true (I set the other suggested flags to true)
2. I tried overriding CreateParams so I could or this value... createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; (I have no idea what this does but read a user suggested to do this.
3. Setting the form DoubleBuffered (does nothing)

Anyways, I can't think what to do and I have read about this for awhile.

Here is my code for all events. I just want to have close buttons on my tabs that get highlighted when I mouse over them. Thanks.

```
    private int mousedOver = -1;//indicates which close button is moused over
    private void tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Index == mousedOver ? Resources.redX : Resources.grayX, e.Bounds.Right - 15, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    }
    private void tabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tc = sender as TabControl;
        if (tc.TabCount == 1) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < tc.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle r = tc.GetTabRect(i);
            Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Top + 4, 12, 12);
            if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                TabPage tp = tc.TabPages[i];
                tc.TabPages.Remove(tp);
                tp.Dispose();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void tabControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tc = sender as TabControl;
        for (int i = 0; i < tc.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle r = tc.GetTabRect(i);
            Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Top + 4, 12, 12);
            if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                mousedOver = i;
                tc.Invalidate();
                return;
            }
        }

        mousedOver = -1;
        tc.Invalidate();
    }
    private void tabControl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tc = sender as TabControl;
        mousedOver = -1;
        tc.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Try creating an array or List of all of those `closeButton` rectangles and populate them during the last "Loading" event for the Form. (Sorry, I forget the order). This way, you're not doing all of that math during every move/click event. Normally, that's not a lot of processing, but during a move event, it really piles up and is causing your UI thread to stutter.

Comment: You should also refactor your code so that you're not repeating yourself so often. The majority of your code between the two events you have is the same.

Comment: Practice best practices now so that when you're developing a real project the better code comes naturally.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - no that's not the way to do it. You need to use the "contact us" form linked at the foot of every page and select the "delete profile" option.

Comment: @chey - use this link https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like you are invalidating too often.  Try filtering it so that you only invalidate it when the control needs to be re-painted:

```
private void tabControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  TabControl tc = sender as TabControl;
  for (int i = 0; i < tc.TabPages.Count; i++) {
    Rectangle r = tc.GetTabRect(i);
    Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Top + 4, 12, 12);
    if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location)) {
      if (mousedOver != i) {
        mousedOver = i;
        tc.Invalidate(r);
      }
    } else if (mousedOver == i) {
      int oldMouse = mousedOver;
      mousedOver = -1;
      tc.Invalidate(tc.GetTabRect(oldMouse));
    }
  }
}
```

I would keep the CreateParams override, but as a native windows control, you can probably never totally eliminate some flicker.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting the DoubleBuffered property of the control, by doing

```
Control.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

I know that this works with DataGridViews, ListViews, Forms and Panels.

Documentation can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx).